# is form API support uploading of 2 gb of data toftp

Tags: forms

I have one application there we have to upload 2 to 3 gb of data in zip format.
So i wonder drupal support any ftp or sftp client integration in drupal or other approaches is available in drupal please guide

Comment: No, not really. Drupal works on HTTP so it cannot upload files from clients using other protocols. Server serving Drupal can even not have FTP/SFTP at all. To allow uploads like that, Drupal would need to serve ftp client applet to user's browser, and give him ftp credentials. That would allow users to upload anything, without using Drupal at all, using it as free anonymous storage. I guess creating open, free for all large file storage is not exactly what you want.

Comment: Can I use storage API of drupal ?

Comment: It will not interfere with transfer from user to your site. It'll only make Drupal to forward http uploaded file via ftp to external storage. On the user<->webserver nothing really changes.

Comment: if my client provide me different storage for those 2 gb files then its good to use storage API :) ?

Comment: Yes, then it is. But it does solve storing side of your problem, not uploading from user side. Could you please clarify your question? Either stating what aspect bothers you, or making clear you know they are kinda separate issues and need to know both.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for replay,yes i have both problem uploading and storage but as per your previous comment provide FTP plugin on browser that sound good,we have to provide ftp client plugin

Comment: By clarifying I meant editing your question to include that directly.

Comment: You could also use HTTP to upload to a custom dir where you can change the upload limits. You can set them on per-directory basis just like http://stackoverflow.com/a/865029/1134063 and than combine this technique with using special storage.